# UILocalNotification not doing anything

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification

This may seem like a silly question, but this is my first time using UILocalNotification and I can't get it to work for a quick test.  It just doesn't do anything.

**1. I've created 2 variables in the AppDelegate**

```
let today = NSDate()
let notification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
```

**2. Then in the applicationDidEnterBackground function, I have the following**

```
    notification.fireDate = today.dateByAddingTimeInterval(10)
    notification.alertTitle = "My App Test"
    notification.alertBody = "Testing Notification \n :)"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

**3. Also added this to the applicationDidBecomeActive function**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

Comment: You are scheduling the notification to be 10 seconds after you create the `today` variable. Are you actually putting the app in the background within 10 seconds of starting it? Did you add all of the needed code to enable and respond to notifications? Did you accept permission to allow notifications for your app?

Comment: Yes, as soon as I launched my app, I put it in the background right away to make sure I was waiting 10 secs. I even saw my log statements making the calls.  In response to your second question, I did find it odd that my App never asked for permission to allow notifications.  But thought nothing of it yet.  How do I force it to ask?

Comment: You should read the [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194) for details.

Comment: Remove `UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)`.

Comment: @rmaddy is correct.  I just read the documentation again and missed a crucial first step which is to register my App first for user notifications.  After I did this it is now working.  I'll add my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading the documentation again, I realized I missed a crucial first step which is to register my App first for user notifications.  The Apple doc was written in OBJ-C, but I was able to figure it out in order to convert it to swift.  This is what I did:

**1. I added this to my AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function and it now works**

```
var types: UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType()
types.insert(UIUserNotificationType.Alert)
types.insert(UIUserNotificationType.Badge)

let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)

UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

Comment: Jesus Christ, I couldn't get it to work and no one mentioned this any where... Thank you!

Comment: I agree, all the examples I've seen never mention this first step.  But glad I was able to figure it out anyway and help anyone else who needs it.